# Run JS code only if a condition is met in URL

Tags: javascript

I would like to run the following code but only if the condition is that the url contains "Mode=edit" somewhere. (If I run it on every page it gives error).

```
<script language='javascript'>
    function Save() {
        __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$btnSave', '');
    }

    function Redirect() {
        window.location = "SessionTimeout.aspx"
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(Save,15000);
    }
</script>
```

How can I have it check for that portion in the url and only then run this script above?

Comment: `if (document.location.href.match('mode=edit')) { .. }`

Comment: `if(window.location.href.indexOf('Mode=edit') !== -1)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an if statement that checks if document.location contains the string.

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('Mode=edit') > -1){ 
    //Your code goes here
}
```